# solution of EDO defined on a specific interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

How can I prove that$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y^{\prime}(t)=1-(t+1) e^{y(t)} \\
y(0)=y_0
\end{array}\right.
$$
the solution is defined in $[0,+\infty)?$.

My teacher said first to prove that $e^{y(t)} \ge \frac{1}{t+1} \forall t\in  $[0,+$T_{max}$)$.$ But how? and second : I know this is the right approach but for me it is not the most natural . Are there faster appproaches?

Comment: Follow the way of your teacher, but to have a reference or second approach you can also explore the transformation $z(t)=e^{-y(t)+t}$ by computing its derivative and inserting.